# Accessing Media Player instance for playing Background Music

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am developing an application which will play azan at specific time, for this I have created an AsynchTask class and whenever time matches with the system time ,player starts playing.
But it gives me a Null Pointer Exception because it fails to access the media player in azan.java. So what is the procedure to access the media player instance in asynchTask class so that I can play in background, though user is on another app screen,player should start playing.

Here is my Code

```
class azanBackground extends AsynchTask<VOID,VOID,VOID>
{
 protected Void doInBackground<Void...params>{
 String temp="2:50 am"
 if(systemTime.equals(temp)){

azan.fplayer.start(); // I am getting a null pointer exception here

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

In order for media to be played in the background of your app location when the user is interacting with it you must start a Service/Broadcast-Receiver from your application's main activity and the service/Broadcast-Receiver shall contain all the methods related to playback. To allow activity to interact with the service, a service connection is also required. In short, we need to implement a bounded service.

Start service with pending intent Like Alarm-service

Refer http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/258176/Adding-Background-Music-to-Android-App

Comment: Thank u, but isn't there a way to access Media Player instance from other class..because I don't want to use service as its not my requirement.

Comment: well you have to create media player instance in BroadcastReceiver and play and Stop in that class. to achieve your reqiirement you can use BroadcastReceiver your AsynchTask not call constantly. to match time

Comment: This is my azan.java....                                            Media Player fplayer=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.azan.mp3) I have inialized it there and in azan activity, I am manually using the play and stop buttons to start and stop media player, but now I want that I could get the instance of fplayer, so that I can use it in my asynchTask class

Comment: I am new in android programming, thats why I have no idea about broadcast reciever and services etc..so expecting an easy way to do this..All my code is complete but azan is not playing because I am not able to access my media player of azan

Comment: Media Player fplayer; defin it Globally  and use that

fplayer=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.azan.mp3) and use it in AsyncTask

Comment: That's why am telling you to use service /BrodcastReceiver is very easy way and you can learn about service/BrodcastReceiver.

Comment: Actually I have a concept that services runs on background even the application is running or not..so I just want to make sure that player only plays when activity is in focus .When user clicks back button it should not play any azan sound

Answer (score 0):

when your application goes into background , it can not notify you that something happen. instead you need to use service which runs in background even when your application is get in background or closed. so add your timing check logic in service and when time matches, it will start the aazaan.

Comment: No, I only want to play azan when user is interacting with the application. It doesn't matter if azan not plays when app goes in background

Comment: so add the start time checking logic or what ever you want to start in onResume() of activity so life cycle of activity start or handle what you want to do.